# Lightweight-charts doesn't show on html page

Tags: javascript, html, charts, lightweight-charts

i'm trying to use a chart on my webpage using Lightweight-charts-library but the chart won't show.
This is my HTMl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type = "module" src="https://unpkg.com/lightweight-charts/dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.production.js"></script>
    <title>Socket Streams</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Trades</h1>

    <div id ="chart"></div>
    <div id ="trades"></div>



    <script>
        var binanceSockets = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/dogebtc@trade")
        var tradeDiv = document.getElementById('trades');

        binanceSockets.onmessage = function (event){
            console.log(event.data);
            var object = JSON.parse(event.data);
            tradeDiv.append(object.p);
        }   
         
    </script>


    <script src="chart.js" type="module"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

My goal is to show a chart on the "chart" div, so I basically copy-pasted this code from the Lightweight-charts library making it to point to chart.

```
import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts';

const chart = createChart(document.getElementById("chart"), { width: 400, height: 300 });
const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries();
lineSeries.setData([
    { time: '2019-04-11', value: 80.01 },
    { time: '2019-04-12', value: 96.63 },
    { time: '2019-04-13', value: 76.64 },
    { time: '2019-04-14', value: 81.89 },
    { time: '2019-04-15', value: 74.43 },
    { time: '2019-04-16', value: 80.01 },
    { time: '2019-04-17', value: 96.63 },
    { time: '2019-04-18', value: 76.64 },
    { time: '2019-04-19', value: 81.89 },
    { time: '2019-04-20', value: 74.43 },
]);
```

if i remove `type = module` from `<script src="chart.js"></script>`i get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.
The javascript's file name is charts.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im assuming you're not using webpack or any bundler.

For the `module` to be considered you'd need to import the library differently  and as follow `import 'https://unpkg.com/lightweight-charts@latest/dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.production.js';` in your `chart.js` script and then use it as advised in the [doc](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/blob/master/docs/README.md#using-a-standalone-version).

Answer (score 1):

make sure put `https://unpkg.com/lightweight-charts/dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.production.js` in your header, it has to be in the header, otherwise won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I used the CDN with unpkg approach to get `lightweight-charts` working in a HTML page.

In my HTML file:

- The URL
  `https://unpkg.com/lightweight-charts/dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.production.js`
  is in the script tag within the header.
- The Javascript file,
  `test.js` is in the script tag within the body.
- `type="module"` is needed in both script tags.

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Chart</title>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/lightweight-charts/dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.production.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black;">

    <!-- create a container for the first chart -->
    <div id="chart1" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <!-- create and configure the first chart -->
    <script type="module" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='test.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript file, test.js, is shown below. Comment out the first two lines:

```
// import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts'; # Comment out this line.

// const chart = createChart(document.getElementById("chart1"), { width: 400, height: 300 }); # Replace this line with the line below.
const chart = LightweightCharts.createChart("chart1", { width: 400, height: 300 });

const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries();
lineSeries.setData([
    { time: '2019-04-11', value: 80.01 },
    { time: '2019-04-12', value: 96.63 },
    { time: '2019-04-13', value: 76.64 },
    { time: '2019-04-14', value: 81.89 },
    { time: '2019-04-15', value: 74.43 },
    { time: '2019-04-16', value: 80.01 },
    { time: '2019-04-17', value: 96.63 },
    { time: '2019-04-18', value: 76.64 },
    { time: '2019-04-19', value: 81.89 },
    { time: '2019-04-20', value: 74.43 },
]);
```